# Refresh $scope automatically

Tags: mysql, angularjs, refresh

I am making an Angular Recipe App which retrieves data from a MySQL database and shows it on the screen. I have a function to "like" the recipe and it just plusses a count to the total likes. But everytime I like it, I have to refresh the page. I would like the scope to refresh it self. I have tried to use the push() function and the apply(), but I cant get it to work. Could someone help me please?

## Dishes.html

```
<div class="" ng-controller='dishesController' >

<div class="dishPanel" ng-repeat='dish in dishes'>
    <div class="imageDishPanel">
        <img ng-src={{dish.link}} />
        <div class="slideBoxDown custFont titleDishPanel">
            {{dish.name}}
        </div>

        <div class="slideBoxUp">
            <div class=" infoTextDishPanel custFont">
                {{dish.info}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="loveDishPanel">
        <div ng-click='getID(dish.id, dish.likes)' class="heart"></div>
        <div class="likes custFont">{{dish.likes}} likes</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

## dishesController.js

```
app.controller('dishesController', ["$scope", "$http","dishesFactory", function($scope, $http, dishesFactory){
dishesFactory.getDataDishesFactory(function(data){
    $scope.dishes = data;
});

$scope.getID = function(id,like){
    $scope.likes  ={
        "id": id,
        "like": like
    };
    $scope.updateLike();
};

$scope.updateLike = function(){
    $http.post("php/updateLike.php",$scope.likes)
        .success(function(data){

        }
    );
};
}]);
```

EDIT: So what I am doing is show all the dishes in the database. Every dish has his "Like" count and Unique ID. If you press the 'like' it will call the getID(id, like); function and that one calls the updateLike function. The updateLike function will send the data (id and the like count) to the updateLike.php file and from there it will add 1 to the original count. The new count will be updated in the database. So on the html page I have to refresh it myself to see the new count. I would like to have the count to refresh it self. To do this i tried to push the data from the success callback in the controller with `$scope.dishes[$scope.id].likes.push(data)`. So I have to push the new like count to the right dish because it is an array of dishes. But i am unable to push it to the right dish..

## updateLike.php

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$id =  $data->id;
$like = (int) $data->like;

$like++;
//$like = var_dump($data->like);

$query = "UPDATE `recipes` SET `likes`='$like' WHERE `id` = '$id' ";
mysql_query($query,$con);


echo $like;
```

Comment: What is the return of the ajax request?

Comment: @neolivz4ever The return from the request is the new value for the like. So if it was 100 and you click on it, it will be updated in the php file and return the value 101. So that is correct, but if I want to see that I have to refresh the page. I would like to have the value be updated by itself

Comment: You just have to updat the $scope variable.

Comment: Yes i know, but i dont know how to exactly update the specific dish. It is an array of dishes and i cant change the $scope.likes of that dish.  i tried to use the following code: $scope.dishes[$scope.id].likes.push(data); But this didnt work. Could you help me with that?

Comment: You need to give more code than that for me to help specific. If you want generic solution how to do this kind of stuff I can write an answer for you.

Comment: @neolivz4ever I edited the question. I hope you understand my struggle

Comment: I added the solution what you are trying to do and added comment on what you should be ideally doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making stuff too complicated. What you want do is simple.

Make the following changes

in html

```
         <div ng-click='getID(dish)' class="heart"></div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.getID = function(dish){
    //Ideally dish.like++ would be done here itself to give instant feeling
    like  ={
        "id": dish.id,
        "like": dish.like
    };
    $scope.updateLike(like, dish);
};

$scope.updateLike = function(like, dish){
    $http.post("php/updateLike.php",like)
        .success(function(data){
            dish.like=data.like;//under the impression the response have like count;
         }
        ).error(function(data){
           //and do dish.like-- if an error happens.
        });
 };
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when i get home.

Comment: Yes thanks! it worked.. and i added the count ++ in the getID function.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't even keeping track of which dish was liked.

In the `.success` function, you'll need something like this;

```
.success(function () {
    // update the likes of the right dish object in $scope.dishes; dishObj.likes++;
});
```

As long as you do that, your view will update automatically. From what it looks like, you aren't really making most of two way data binding that `AngularJS` is best known for ;-)

Comment: yes i did.. I send the array likes with 'id' and 'like' to my php file so i know which one i need to update. In my PHP file I add 1 to the 'like' count and send that value back to the controller and update it in my database. I tried to do a push() in my success() but it didn't work or i dont know how to do it.
I also dont know how to update the exact dish in the array. I know the new 'like' count and the 'ID' number of the dish but i dont know how to update that one specific variable. I tried to push it with this code:
$scope.dishes[$scope.id].likes.push(data); but it didnt work